# Golang test coverage with black box _test coverage

Tags: testing, go

My problem is simple, but the answer remains elusive. Suppose I have a package

```
package mypackage

func DoTheThing() int {
  return 5
}
```

Now suppose I have a test using in the `mypackage_test` package

```
package mypackage_test

import "testing"
import . "mypackage"

func TestDoTheThing(t *testing.T) {
    if DoTheThing() != 5 {
        t.Error("there was a problem")
    }
}
```

Now I want to know the code coverage of the package `mypackage`.

```
$ go test -cover
PASS
coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      /my/path/mypackage 0.002s
```

It should be 100%. I have tried also

```
$ go test -v -cover -coverpkg ./... ./...
=== RUN   TestDoTheThing
--- PASS: TestDoTheThing (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 0.0% of statements in ./...
ok      /my/path/mypackage 0.002s  coverage: 0.0% of statements in ./...
```

It is not a possibility for me to include the test in `mypackage`, so I need to know the code coverage of `mypackage` in this setup.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

After much keyboard mashing, I discovered it has to do with the fact that I was simlinking my project directory to `$GOPATH/src/`.

Copying the project into `$GOPATH/src/mypackage` and running `go test -cover` correctly returns 100% coverage.